# Illustrator pattern with blend mode shows dark lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, blend-modes

How can I get rid of these dark lines in my pattern?

They only appear when I apply some sort of blend mode to my objects. These particular objects have multiply blend mode applied to them and the dark lines appear where the pattern "connects" in a grid.

I don't want to get rid of the blend mode, I need it for the desired look, but it's definitely the thing that causes the lines. Any advice?

[image: pattern with dark lines]

The swatch looks like this. It seems like an overlap to me too, but I created the box as a 6x6 square and duplicated objects by moving them by exactly 6 inches. Also in the Pattern tool I set 6 inches as the size of the tile. What's interesting is that when the Pattern tool shows me the preview of how the pattern will look, there is no overlap. Even when I set 9x9 preview so there are many repeats. It only shows later when the pattern is applied to a shape.

[image: pattern tile]

Comment: Could you post a screengrab of the pattern swatch itself - or drag it out of the patterns palette onto the artboard so we can examine the relationship between the pattern and its bounds? I ask because the simplest answer is that on those two sides there's a slight mismatch between the pattern bounding box and the actual pattern, and so you're getting literal overlap on those sides, hence those black lines. I might try redefining a new version of the pattern in which you intentionally make the pattern not fill the bounds, then gradually increase till they touch as a test.

Comment: If you output the file (web image art optimized or PDF) does the stitching still show? Sometimes it is merely an on-screen issue with anti-aliasing.

Comment: @Scott yes, it still shows after exporting to any format, even PDF. I also have art optimized (supersampling) set as a default, so I don't believe that's an issue.

Comment: Okay. All I could really suggest then is to flatten transparency for the pattern *tile*.. then apply transparency to the fill after it's been applied.. if it's needed.

Comment: @Scott I tried zooming in REALLY close (6400%) and the line disappears. However, after any kind of export, it's still there. Does it mean it's a visual/export bug? Concerning your advice, I don't really understand what you suggest. Could you clarify?

Comment: It's *probably* due to anti-aliasing. What I'd suggest is that you flatten all transparency for the *tile*... select all the art and choose `Edit > Flatten Transparency`. This **will** alter the objects, So try it on a *copy* of the art first. If there is no transparency on the pattern tile itself, then this 1-2px anti-alias area won't be a problem. I **can't** say for certain this will work. I've honestly never used transparency in any pattern tile the way you are.

Comment: @Scott thank you, the Flatten Transparency option worked! I didn't even know there's such a thing in Illustrator, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to anti-aliasing.

What I'd suggest is that you **flatten all transparency** for the **tile**...

Select all the art and choose `Edit > Flatten Transparency`.

This **will** alter the objects. So try it *on a copy* of the art first.

If there is no transparency on the pattern tile itself, then this 1-2px anti-alias area shouldn't be a problem.

Disclaimer: I can't say for certain this will work. I've honestly never used transparency in any pattern tile the way you are using it.

Comment: I agree. What about applying transparency to the pattern afterwards. Like make totally nontransparent patter then apply transparency in the effects tab. Anyway the conflation error is a bitch when it comes to patterns.